# How to fill xls file without blank rows?

Tags: java, excel, report

I am trying to generate an excel file on my project. My aim is to display all department and all student assigned in this particular department. So far this is what i did:

```
...
int rowNum = 4;//From row 0 to 3 was occupied as Header
for (Department department : departments) {
    Row row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
    row.createCell(0).setCellValue(department.getName());
    for (Students student: students) {
        row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
        if (department.getId() == student.getDepartmentId()) {
            row.createCell(0).setCellValue(student.getIdNumber());
            //and all other info such as name, gender, dob
        }
    }
}
```

If **one department is selected then it works fine, however if i choose to get all department** my output goes like this:

```
Department A
//blank rows of about 20 were produced
201901010          Student A          Male          ...
201901011          Student B          Male          ...
//blank rows of about 950
Department B
//blank rows of about 40
201901071          Student X          Male          ...
201901072          Student Z          Male          ...
//blank rows of about 963
...
```

What i want is something like this:

```
Department A
201901010          Student A          Male          ...
201901011          Student B          Male          ...
Department B
201901071          Student X          Male          ...
201901072          Student Z          Male          ...
...
```

I tried different things on my **rowNum** variables but none of them works. Some just printed all my Department and a lot of blank rows and then it printed the list of students under the last Department.

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that the structured of my code is wrong:

```
if (department.getId() == student.getDepartmentId()) {
    row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
    ....
}
```

instead of:

```
row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
if (department.getId() == student.getDepartmentId()) {
    row.createCell(0).setCellValue(student.getIdNumber());
    ...
}
```